# Query mysql continua sendo executada após Lost Connection?

Tags: mysql

Estou utilizando o MySQL Workbench para executar uma query de remoção de dados duplicados. Quando eu executo a query para uma tabela muito grande, devido ao limite de 600seg de conexão do Workbench, ele resulta em Lost Connection. Mesmo assim, os valores duplicados desaparecem. Aí me surgiu a dúvida:
O código que estou utilizando para verificar se há linhas repetidas é:

```
SELECT TS_SAMPLETM, COUNT(*) FROM HT_MA2_SBX_SEG
GROUP BY TS_SAMPLETM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Mesmo o Workbench perdendo conexão com o servidor, a query é executada até o final?

Comment: Bom não sei te confirmar, mas quando você tem uma conxão e executa uma query ela já foi, você apenas está esperando o servidor responder, se der timeout o servidor aborta e o que foi, e o que não foi não foi, ou seja, tem o risco de não ter executado até o final, melhor rever sua query, não poderia demorar tanto pra responder

Comment: Entendi. Eu tenho cerda de 30 milhões de linhas de dados, por isso deve estar demorando esse tempo. Mas, como eu disse, utilizando um código que retorna as linhas duplicadas, o select sempre retorna vazio, o que indica que o código para deletar as linhas duplicadas funcionou mesmo perdendo conexão.

Comment: Pode ser que está executando tudo a tempo mas o banco está se perdendo pra dizer que deu sucesso, aí explica pq da timeout

Comment: Faz sentido. Só gostaria de confirmar mesmo, além de verificar se o código que retorna as linhas duplicadas está ok. Obrigado!

Comment: Você chama sua rotina em uma aplicação?

Comment: Não. Estou executando tudo direto do MySQL Workbench,